# Integrate firebase with Parse

Tags: parse-platform, firebase, jwt

I am trying to integrate Firebase with Parse to use Parse users in Firebase. I am trying to use "Custom Authentication" feature in Firebase. For this I have to create JWT (JASON Web Token) using Parse Cloud. To achieve this I am using "jsrsasign" library but not able to create Token. Is there any tutorial or code snippet to generate JWT in Parse Cloud?

Comment: For those curious why these two combinations may be used together; it is most likely where Firebase provides and offline mobile database and Parse is to being used for Push notification as a service.

With Parse being depreciated in the near future; the alternative consideration can be the Couchbase Mobile stack.  This is an offline mobile database solution for apps across all platforms and with Synchronization abstracted.  Push notification can be done natively using 'toast' messages with the sync provided from Couchbase Mobile here.